# Shell script to find and move files and delete the affected folders

Tags: file, shell, command, directory

Is it possible to create a shell script that finds files in and below a folder of a specific type, and move them to another folder (this part is already solved*). And then remove all folders where files were moved from?

I guess it should be somehow possible to write the path/folder name into an array or file and then read from there to "**rm**" them.

finding files example:

```
find . \( -name "*.mpeg" – o –name "*.mkv" –o –name "*.avi" –o –name "*.mov" \) –size +536870912c –exec mv  -n –v {} /my/favorite/folder/ \;
```

second part where those folders from which was moved need to be deleted is still missing.

Answer (score 0):

If you din't mind using another executables, you can do it like:

```
find . \( -name "*.mpeg" – o –name "*.mkv" –o –name "*.avi" –o –name "*.mov" \) –size +536870912c | \
gawk -F'/[^/]*$' '{print "echo mv " $0 " /WHERE/TO/MOVE" ; dirstoremove[$1]++ } 
       END       {for (d in dirstoremove) {print "echo rmdir " d } }' | \
bash
```

1. First `find` your items
2. Then `gawk` creates the list of removable files and store their path in an array and after processing all the files prints the `rmdir` for every element in the array
3. And sends it output to `bash` which executes it.

***Note***: the above won't remove anything just `echo`es what should be done. If you are satisfied with the result and want to execute it you can remove the two "`echo`" or simply add one more `| bash` to the end.

Answer (score 0):

If you like one-liners (like I do), you can extend your command as follows:

```
<your find command> -print | xargs -l dirname | sort -u | xargs rmdir
```

`-print` echoes the path of the file that has been moved.

`xargs -l dirname` strips off the filenames, resulting in a list of directory names.

`sort -u` reduces the list of directory names by removing duplicates.

`xargs rmdir` removes the directories.